# Android vibration making on .wav file

Tags: android, vibration

I have a .wav file, I want to extract that .wav file to corresponding vibration signal and vibrate in android phone with same amplitude that .wav file consists. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think you can specify the amplitude (strength) of the vibration? You may be able to simulate weaker vibration by "dithering", quickly turning it on and off.

Anyway, what you will need is an "envelope curve" for your sound file, basically a very low frequency volume curve.

Comment: look what I want is to get a long array of amplitude which will be passed into Vibrator.vibrate(long[] array, 0), is it the right approach?

Comment: This call won't let you modulate the amplitude directly: "values alternate between durations in milliseconds to turn the vibrator off or to turn the vibrator on", that's why I am suggesting dithering. The resolution is 1 millisecond in theory, but I am sure the physical device responds much slower than that, that's why I'm suggesting the envelope curve.